# Intercept ThreadContext of log4j2 in Spring AOP Around Advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2, spring-aop

- I have a spring web-app which receives some URI request from UI and calls business logic in Service classes to perform a certain operation.

  - I'm using log4j2 JDBC logging to log in Database.
  - Now I want to log session-Id in a different column in Database. And for this, I'm using ThreadContext Map to pass session-Id to be saved as mentioned here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Below is a snapshot of how I'm using:

log4j configuration:

```
<Appenders>
        <Jdbc ignoreExceptions="true" name="db-appender"
        bufferSize="${env:LOG_DB_BUFFER_SIZE}" tableName="test.&quot;LOGS&quot;">
        <ConnectionFactory class="com.pritam.logging.ConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
        <Column name="dated" isUnicode="false" isEventTimestamp="true" />
        <Column name="logger" isUnicode="false" pattern="%logger" />
        <Column name="level" isUnicode="false" pattern="%level" />
        <Column name="message" isUnicode="false" pattern="%message" />
        <Column name="exception" isUnicode="false" pattern="%ex{full}" />
        <Column name="session_id" isUnicode="false" pattern="%X{session_id}"/>
    </Jdbc>
</Appenders>
```

Sample method:

```
public void doSomething(String id, JobHeader jobHeader) {
    ThreadContext.put("session_id", jobHeader.getContext().getSessionId());

    //Business Logic
    logger.debug("Logging Message");
    //Business Logic

    ThreadContext.clearAll();        
}
```

This works fine. And logs session id in a different column.

Now, I have n numbers of **doSomething** methods which are going to be executed in independent threads having various session-ids. 
And I don't want to write ThreadContext Statements over and over again, So I'm thinking of using Spring-AOP advice (@Around Advice) for this task.

Can someone please explain to me how to inject the ThreadContext in @Around advice in Spring-AOP.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something along these lines

Say I have a component

```
@Component
public class MyService { 
    public void doSomething() { ... } 
}
```

I then define as aspect for it:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyServiceAspect { 
    @Before("execution(* <packages>.MyService.doSomething())")
    public void beforeDoSomething() {
        ThreadContext.put("key", "value");
    }

    @After("execution(* <packages>.MyService.doSomething())")
    public void afterDoSomething() {
        ThreadContext.clearAll(); 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Radu , thanks for the answer. I'm also using it same way as of now.